# How to create a custom segue that will slide the new view in from right to left in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked at several examples and it looks like this used to be the default effect for a Push segue which is now deprecated. The new default animation for a Show or Present Modally segue is to have the new view slide in from the bottom to the top.

I am using the code below after looking through several examples of how to create your own custom segue. I am getting the effect that I want which is to have the new view slide in from the right to the left right until the end of the animation. Right at the end, when the new view is fully displayed on the screen, there is a fort of blink, where for a few seconds I see the old view and then the new view is presented again.

Please help! Thanks.

```
    class CustomStoryboardSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC = self.destinationViewController

        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( sourceVC.view.frame.size.width, 0)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1.0, 1.0)

            }) { (finished) -> Void in
                destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

                let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

To clarify the finished block in my code above, I delay the presentation of the view controller by a second to avoid getting the

**error: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for TableViewController**

because I cannot remove the source view and present the destination view at the exact same time.

To test this I removed the delay and updated my finished block as follows and now I am getting the 'unbalanced call error' as expected but, interestingly enough, I am also seeing the blink at the end of the transition.

```
}) { (finished) -> Void in
            destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

            sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
```

Comment: why in your completion handler do you delay the presenting of the VC by 0.001 sec? it sounds like why you are having a problem... (actually, does that `time` var even get used?)

Comment: you are right, I edited my question to show I use the time variable now. The reason I am doing this is to avoid creating an unbalanced call, I need to remove the source view and present the new view a little bit after, cannot be done at the exact same time. But, I agree with you that perhaps I am not doing it correctly because of the blink I see a the end. I wrote my finished block using this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfPZ93yvAko

Comment: i think you need to focus on figuring out why you are getting that unbalanced call error rather than try cheat it by delaying the presentation of the vc, you definitely should be able to remove the source view and present at the same time.

Comment: If you want to slid from right to left you can get this result by Show segue.
create Show segue between two viewControllers and then select first and embed in Navigation Controller.

Comment: after that hide the navigation bar on both ViewControllers.

Comment: Thank you Abdul, your solution worked for me.